# Not sure if I need a formula or formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to define a value for individual columns only if data is present, then calculate the sum of the data in another column. I am creating this for users that have basic excel knowledge so I'm trying to only have to have them put a value of "x" in the column and have that translate into a numerical value based on what column it's in. This is for an employee score card to help with annual reviews so the column values would be -5 to 5.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: An example would go a long way to help us understand. Can you provide sample data with the desired output?

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:
using index() and match().
Have shown the functions separately (cells I4 & I6) and combined together (cell I2) ...

[image: example laid out]

Comment: Love INDEX and MATCH, probably my most used formulas, also OFFSET & MATCH can do some cool 'two' step lookups

Comment: there are some opinions about offset() on stack overflow :) due to the calculation overhead, but it has its uses IMHO. Thanks for the feedback though - cheers